# To keep SIgned in web whats_App on Web View

Tags: android-studio, webview

i am making an android application that includes one ***web_View***. i loaded **web_Whats_App** on it. so i want keep signed in web Whats_app on it. then what is my **code**?

Comment: post what you tried